# Visual Studio Code - Golang debugging: How to see the value of a pointer time.Time?

Tags: debugging, go, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code to debug a Golang project, and I have no idea how to read the value of a pointer to time.Time variable.

Here is an example:

[image]

I am not sure what `wall, ext, loc` stand for, and the only way I can read the value here is to add a log command:

```
log.Infof("%v", paymentAt.Format("20060102"))
```

Is there a better way to view the value while debugging?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not currently. Under the covers Visual Studio Code uses delve for it's debugging and they have an open request to add this capability:

https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/999